# beacon interval, DTIM interval, & their effect on the network throughput/latency?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, 802.11n, multicast, broadcast

what effect does having beacon interval, DTIM interval set to a higher or lower value have on a wireless network latency? if I understand correctly if a network only has one AP, then setting the beacon interval to the highest possible shouldn't have any side effects, except for it & DTIM affecting broadcasts & multicast, but what's an example for broadcast/multicast in a home network & what kind of applications get affected, for example do they effect latency sensitive games like csgo, do they affect the delays of push notifications on phones & so on?